# Oracle SQL merging rows with same id and combining column results

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have a query like this:

```
select
a.date,
a.id,
b.name,
a.data1,
a.data2,
a.data3
from table a,
inner join table b on a.id=b.id.
```

It returns me data similar to this:

| A.DATE | A.ID | B.NAME | A.DATA1 | A.DATA2 | A.DATA3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06.08.22 | 12345 | Name1 | 10 | 5 | 5 |
| 06.08.22 | 12345 | name1 | 15 | 3 | 2 |
| 06.08.22 | 34567 | name2 | 6 | 1 | 5 |
| 06.08.22 | 45678 | name3 | 2 | 2 | 4 |

I need the result to look like this if there are rows with repeating ID:

| A.DATE | A.ID | B.NAME | A.DATA1 | A.DATA2 | A.DATA3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **06.08.22** | **12345** | **Name1** | **25** | **8** | **7** |
| 06.08.22 | 34567 | name2 | 6 | 1 | 5 |
| 06.08.22 | 45678 | name3 | 2 | 2 | 4 |

As in take rows with same ID and only show 1 row and sum the DATA results in their own columns

I've tried using listagg but it doesn't seem to work.

```
select
a.date,
listagg(a.ID, ',') within group (order by null),
b.name,
sum(a.data1),
sum(a.data2),
sum(a.data3)
from table a,
inner join table b on a.id=b.id.
```

I get results like this:

| A.DATE | A.ID | B.NAME | A.DATA1 | A.DATA2 | A.DATA3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06.08.22 | **12345,12345** | Name1 | 10 | 5 | 5 |
| 06.08.22 | **12345,12345** | name1 | 15 | 3 | 2 |
| 06.08.22 | 34567 | name2 | 6 | 1 | 5 |
| 06.08.22 | 45678 | name3 | 2 | 2 | 4 |

Am I using listagg wrong or something else is missing?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use GROUP BY clause for non-aggregated columns while getting rid of LISTAGG without forgetting the case conversion for the name column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a self join, each of the columns other than id can use an aggregate function:

- For the data1,data2,data3 columns, use `SUM` for obvious reasons
- For the dt column (date is a reserved word in oracle and should not be used as a column name), use `MIN` or `MAX` (depending on your requirements). If you do not use an aggregate function you need to include this column in the `GROUP BY` clause and it could show multiple rows if different dates exist for the same id.
- For the name column, use `MIN` or `MAX` (depending on your requirements). If you do not use an aggregate function you need to include this column in the `GROUP BY` clause and it could show multiple rows if different names exist for the same id.

```
-- create test data
CREATE TABLE tablea (dt,  id, name, data1,data2,data3) AS
(
SELECT TO_DATE('06.08.22','DD.MM.YY'),  12345,  'Name1' ,10,    5,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('06.08.22','DD.MM.YY'),  12345,  'name1' ,15,    3,  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('06.08.22','DD.MM.YY'),  34567,  'name2' ,6, 1,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('06.08.22','DD.MM.YY'),  45678,  'name3' ,2, 2,  4 FROM DUAL
);


SELECT
  MIN(dt)    AS min_dt,
  id,
  MIN(name)  AS min_name,
  SUM(data1) AS data1,
  SUM(data2) AS data2,
  SUM(data3) AS data3
  FROM
  tablea
 GROUP BY
  id;

MIN_DT              ID MIN_N      DATA1      DATA2      DATA3
----------- ---------- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
06-AUG-2022      45678 name3          2          2          4
06-AUG-2022      12345 Name1         25          8          7
06-AUG-2022      34567 name2          6          1          5
```

Comment: Thank you Koen Lostrie, this has solved the issue, thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help